# Get multiple of two textbox values if both are disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get multiple of two textboxes on change of any of it. But cannot allow user to input manually so these 2 will be disabled and will be filled from dropdown.

Edit: If I change the value manually or atleast tab through the textboxes(when it's open to do that) it's working fine (But if I change .change to .keyup). But if I change the value of textbox s_wageperday on change of another dropdown list I'm not getting the multiple on the third box.

```
<?php
/*start getting Wage Amount amount*/
$script = <<<EOD
$(function() {
     $("#totaldays").change(function() {  
        totalWage();
    });

    $("#salary-s_wageperday").change(function() {  
        totalWage();
    });

    var totalWage = function () {
      var days = parseInt($("#totaldays").val());
      var wagePerday = parseInt($("#salary-s_wagePerday").val());
      var totalWage = (days * wagePerday);

      if (isNaN(totalWage) || totalWage < 0 || totalWage > 1000000) {
        totalWage = '';
        }

      $("#salary-s_totalwage").val(totalWage);
    };

 });
EOD;
$this->registerJs($script, View::POS_END);
/*end getting totalwage*/       
?>
```

Comment: *"change is not working. If I use keyup it's working."* - The `change` event isn't triggered until the user leaves the field (via the tab key or by clicking somewhere else with the mouse). If you're trying to change the value of the textboxes programmatically based on the selected value in dropdowns then please [edit] your question to explain that in more detail - include the relevant html.

Comment: Edited the title and explained clearly in the question. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

.change event only works if there a change on dropdown value, but you can trigger it using the $.trigger("change") method.

by the way are you using type="text", have you considered using type="hidden" since you don't want the value to be altered manually.

Hope you get some ideas here pal :)

EDITED

Hi there I'm confused with your post title so I made a changes. Do you mean "Get the product of textbox" right?

Kindly check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jeorlie/ds5f7nrb/1/

You can see the

```
$.trigger("change")
```

method there

I hope this can be a help to you pal.

Comment: Hi Edang as suggested bu nnnnnn in the comment I have clarified the question a bit. Please have a look. What I want is when any of the textbox value will be changed the 3rd textbox that is the result will be changed. I can make the input boxes hidden or disabled. Can you please help how to use $.trigger("change") method. I'm not so sure about it.

Comment: Kindly check the fiddle I just added. :)

Answer (score 0):

lets check on this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yg48wka5/.
and i think you have miss in typo that are

```
$("#salary-s_wagePerday") or $("#salary-s_wageperday")
```

what is the correct P or p.
sorry for my bad english.
i hope that will help you.

Comment: $("#salary-s_wageperday") is fine.

Comment: this one is fine too.. :)

Comment: But this is not what I'm looking for.